# Accessing docker container app running on guest KVM from Ubuntu host

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, virtualization, kvm, windows-server-2016

**My setup is:**

1. Ubuntu server 16.04 running on headless appliance (host)
2. Windows server 2016 KVM (guest) running on top of the host.
3. Network type between host and guest is NAT.  The whole thing is behind corp. proxy.
4. The host is getting static IP from the corp gateway.

On the KVM I'm running docker container app that is listening on port 15417 from inside and outside (docker ps: 0.0.0.0:15417 -> 15417/tcp)
The container IP address is 192.168.122.35, while the KVM IP address from NAT is: 192.168.122.82

The app running on the docker container is exposing an API that should be accessed from the linux host on kvm_ip:15417/api

**The facts:**

1. Port 15417 is opened on the windows FW for inbound TCP connection.
2. There is a working ping from the host to kvm IP (192.168.122.82)
3. The app api can be accessed on 192.168.122.35:15417/api
4. docker logs, displays logs so the app is up and running.

**The problems:**

1. The API cannot be accessed from the KVM on localhost:15417/api or 127.0.0.1:15417/api, the response I get for `curl localhost:15417/api` is:

> Destination host unreachable

2. The API cannot be accessed from 192.168.122.82:15417/api (KVM_IP) on host, same response on `curl 192.168.122.82:15417/api` as on the kvm powershell.
3. No telnet to 192.168.122.82 15417 from host or telnet 127.0.0.1 15417 from guest, while telnet to other ports like RDP (3389) or vnc (5900) is working fine, meaning the ports are all open.

Here's my host 'ifconfig':

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:0b:67:e3:4c
      inet addr:172.28.69.86  Bcast:172.28.69.87  Mask:255.255.255.248
      inet6 addr: fe80::290:bff:fe67:e34c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:89816 (89.8 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

br-ef89294aca4b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:3d:dc:07:b1
      inet addr:172.20.0.1  Bcast:172.20.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:3dff:fedc:7b1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:80271 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:51030 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:98712118 (98.7 MB)  TX bytes:4318906 (4.3 MB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ea:f9:4a:a6
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:0b:67:e3:4b
      inet addr:172.28.69.84  Bcast:172.28.69.255
```

Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: fe80::290:bff:fe67:e34b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:43437560 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28285024 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:50031414909 (50.0 GB)  TX bytes:5610346118 (5.6 GB)
          Memory:df800000-df8fffff

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:0b:67:e3:4c
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Memory:dfe00000-dfe7ffff

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2528921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2528921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:3180228446 (3.1 GB)  TX bytes:3180228446 (3.1 GB)

veth38444b2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b2:43:0f:a2:0e:34
      inet6 addr: fe80::b043:fff:fea2:e34/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1728 (1.7 KB)  TX bytes:816 (816.0 B)

veth55c3534 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:e3:a5:c0:54:84
      inet6 addr: fe80::50e3:a5ff:fec0:5484/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4329603 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4447953 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1018418030 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:1107337021 (1.1 GB)

vetha9c713b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:96:67:47:1c:72
      inet6 addr: fe80::96:67ff:fe47:1c72/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:175785 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:124544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:45484242 (45.4 MB)  TX bytes:22613601 (22.6 MB)

vethcfde2a8 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ca:ab:04:da:b6:98
      inet6 addr: fe80::c8ab:4ff:feda:b698/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:990878 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1367424 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:212266708 (212.2 MB)  TX bytes:287696403 (287.6 MB)

vethd045150 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:b0:0f:df:b3:ec
      inet6 addr: fe80::40b0:fff:fedf:b3ec/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:431061 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:423829 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:102897883 (102.8 MB)  TX bytes:91172674 (91.1 MB)

vethe3e3d6f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:21:a7:44:81:7d
      inet6 addr: fe80::7421:a7ff:fe44:817d/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1598 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:597484 (597.4 KB)  TX bytes:350579 (350.5 KB)

vethf34ccaa Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:a9:29:e3:b5:2c
      inet6 addr: fe80::74a9:29ff:fee3:b52c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2674 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3783 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:4805257 (4.8 MB)  TX bytes:689076 (689.0 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:17:94:ca
      inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:23845306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:31454109 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1454280991 (1.4 GB)  TX bytes:48875445867 (48.8 GB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:fc:b7:f1
      inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fefc:b7f1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4512098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4084521 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:580069804 (580.0 MB)  TX bytes:2979706156 (2.9 GB)
```

And my KVM (guest) networking default config:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>9f80b5ad-b4fa-4c7e-a559-d27c23328347</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:17:94:ca'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

And finally the KVM network interface configuration is:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:fc:b7:f1'/>
  <source network='default' bridge='virbr0'/>
  <target dev='vnet0'/>
  <model type='rtl8139'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

I struggling while trying to find out what is interrupting ,me from accessing the app on KVM from the host.

Comment: Did you solve your problem somehow?

Comment: I finally solved the problem. The problem was that the docker container on the KVM was not attached to the docker NAT network. As soon as I've attached it the NAT network, problem resolved.